# React - how to render nested object with renderItem

Tags: django, reactjs, django-rest-framework, antd

I'm a bit struggling with rendering nested object in my front end. I know there is a map function might be helpful, but I'm not sure how I can get it to work in my case (with `renderItem`). The back end I'm using are Rest API framework and Django.

This is what JSON structure looks like.

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Job 1",
    "address": [
        {
            "id": 4,
            "street": "65 Karamea Street",
            "suburb": "Beautiful Surburb",
            "town": "Christchurch",
            "postcode": "8001",
            "address_type": "h"
        }
    ],
    "franchise": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Company ABC",
        "person": 2,
        "legal_name": "Company ABC Ltd.",
        "created": "2019-08-09T09:40:35.697582Z",
        "modified": "2019-09-23T03:21:43.258983Z",
        "region": {
            "id": 4,
            "region": "QueensTown"
        }
    },
    "customer1": {
        "id": 1,
        "last_name": "Tom",
        "first_name": "Wilson",
        "address": [
            {
                "id": 11,
                "street": "1 Sunset Road",
                "suburb": "Auckland",
                "town": "Auckland",
                "postcode": "1234"
            }
        ]
}
```

This is the React code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { List, Card } from 'antd';


const Job = props => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <List
        grid={{
          gutter: 16,
          xs: 1,
          sm: 2,
          md: 4,
          lg: 4,
          xl: 6,
          xxl: 3,
        }}
        dataSource={props.data}
        renderItem={item => (
          <List.Item>
            <Card title={<a href={`/job/${item.id}`}>{item.customer1.first_name}</a>}>{item.franchise.legan_name}
                                    <span> | Based on </span>
                                    {item.name}
            </Card>
          </List.Item>
        )}
      />
      </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default Job;
```

Within the `card` object, I wish to render the `first_name` of `customer1` and the `legal_name` of `franchise`. Apparently `item.customer1.first_name` and `item.franchise.legal_name` aren't working.

I'm NEW to React, any help would be much appreciated! It would be great if you could provide some actual code just to be specific.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Is `props.data` an array of Job objects, as shown in your structure example?

Comment: @DacreDenny hi it's the JSON data via API.

Answer (score 1):

You are not sending array of jobs but an object to List.

Changes done:-

1) Converted the passed object into array.

2) Corrected name of attribute `item.franchise.legal_name`

Below is the working code:-

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { List, Card } from "antd";


class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <List
          grid={{
            gutter: 16,
            xs: 1,
            sm: 2,
            md: 4,
            lg: 4,
            xl: 6,
            xxl: 3
          }}
          dataSource={new Array(this.props.data)}
          renderItem={item => (
            <List.Item>
              <Card
                title={
                  <a href={`/job/${item.id}`}>{item.customer1.first_name}</a>
                }
              >
                {item.franchise.legal_name}
                <span> | Based on </span>
                {item.name}
              </Card>
            </List.Item>
          )}
        />
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: Thanks mate for the detailed reply, but what I wanted to render is not an constant (like `data` in your example), but instead some JSON data from API. How do I make the payload dynamic?

Comment: This was an example to demonstrate completeness of code and show it works with array. Use `props.data` instead of `data`. Its just props.data should be an array instead of object. You could do `dataSource={newArray(props.data)}` to convert object into array.

Comment: I have changed my code to use props `data` instead of `data` constant.

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply, but in your example, `props` would be undefined? I also tried to keep it as `const Job = props => {..`, and React give me this error. `TypeError: Cannot read property 'first_name' of undefined`

Comment: The current code is not fully functional to let you understand the gist. can you use `this.props` instead of `props`. I have also updated my code.

Comment: Hey I'm still having exactly the same errors with `this.` added... Is the idea to convert the JSON data into array so that we can access the nested elements with dot syntax? Do you think map function would work in this case?

Answer (score 0):

In order to show your JSON data you should use `map` in your render()
This is how map works

```
render(){return(
 < div>{this.state.mydata.map(m=><div>{m.  name < /div> })
 < /div>
);
```

Now in order to use your nested data
In the map you can map `m` again (like m.map(...) )

Hope you get the idea and works for you

Comment: Sorry could you please be more specific?